# How can I get my method to search another method for a variable?

Tags: java, methods

```
import java.io.*;
public class carwip2
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        getAverageCarSales();
        getBonus();
    }
    public static void getAverageCarSales()
    {
        Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
        int total_car_sold=0, no_car_sold=0 , z=0;
        int yr_no=0;
        int yrs=0;


        float average_sold=0F;

        System.out.println("Enter number of years");
        yr_no=sc.nextInt();
        if (!isValid(yr_no))
        {

            return;
        }

        for (int i=0; i<yr_no; i++)
        {
            System.out.println("Enter the year");
            yrs=sc.nextInt();
            if (!isValid(yrs))
            {

                return;
            }
            for (int j=0;j<6;j++)
            {
                System.out.println("Enter number of cars sold for year " + yrs + " in month #" + (j+1));
                no_car_sold=sc.nextInt();
                if (!isValid(no_car_sold))
                {

                    return;
                }
                total_car_sold=no_car_sold + total_car_sold;
            }
        }
            System.out.println("Total number of months:" + (yr_no*6) );
            System.out.println("Total number of cars sold: " + total_car_sold);
            average_sold = total_car_sold / (yr_no * 6);
            System.out.println("Average number of cars sold per month: " + average_sold);
    }
    public static void getBonus()
    {
        double bonus=0;
        if(average_sold>25)
        {
            bonus=(yr_no * 6) * (500) * (average_sold - 25);
        }
        bonus= bonus-(bonus*.0825);
        System.out.println("The bonus is: " +bonus);
    }
    public static boolean isValid(int x)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

What I'm trying to do with my code is to get my method getBonus to read/find where average_sold is. I've tried putting getBonus(getAverageCarSales), but I wasn't sure what identifier I could use to do so. So, what can I change/incorporate to help my getBonus method find average_sold further up in my coding?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you make average_sold a class level variable! that way any method in that class can access it.

```
public class carwip2
{
 float average_sold = 0f;
 public static void main(String [] args)
  {
    //your code here
  }
   //rest of your code
```

Answer (score 0):

The name of the function getAverageCarSales has the hint to what you need to do. Return the value of average_sold and use it as a input parameter of getBonus:

Edit: Changed the code considering both variables.

```
public class carwip2
{
    private static float average_sold = 0f;
    private static int yr_no = 0;

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        getAverageCarSales();
        getBonus();
    }

    public static void getAverageCarSales()
    {            
        //dont initialize average_sold and yr_no here. 
        //(...)
    }

    public static void getBonus() 
    {
        //(...)
    }  

}
```

Comment: I made the edits you suggested but now, it can't find yr_no in the line bonus=(yr_no * 6) * (500) * (average_sold - 25)... how or where can I move yr_no so that it can be found?

Comment: Oh.. didn't saw that. You'll need make yr_no and average_sold static variables.